# Terraform output from several resources generated with count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have these outputs:

```
output "ec2_id" {
   value = aws_instance.ec2instance[*].id
}
output "ec2_name" {
   value = aws_instance.ec2instance[*].tags["Name"]
}
output "ec2_mgmt_eip" {
   value = aws_eip.eip_mgmt_ec2instance[*].public_ip
}
```

I want to make an output like:

`"<instanceName>: <instanceID> -> <publicIP>"` 
(all data in same line for same ec2 instance).
In any non-declarative language i can use something like `for (var i=0; i<length(myarray);i++)` and use "i" as index for each list, in every index concatenate in a new string, but in terraform I can't find how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for

Comment: can you give me an example? I think, maybe, I misunderstand the documentation of "for" expression

Comment: `value = { for i in aws_instance.ec2instance : i.tags["Name"] => i.id }`

Comment: Not sure on the exact object format for count. Usage of that should mostly be replaced with `for_each` in terraform > 0.12.

Comment: thank you @jordanm I misunderstand the doc and where to extract the info. and tried to extract from eip and instance, but I only need the instance info, like you exampled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you got the answer in the comments, I will add an example. So, the thing you want does exist in terraform as it also has `for` loops [1]. A `for` loop along with the right syntax will give you a desired output, which is a map in terraform:

```
output "ec2_map" {
  value = { for i in aws_instance.ec2instance: i.tags.Name => "${i.id}:${i.public_ip}" }
}
```

The output you said you want is quite similar to this. Also, there is no concept of "same line" in terraform. In this case, since this is a map, the keys will be instance names and value will be a combination of instance id and the public IP, but that will be a string.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for